# How to put a delete button beneath each post?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

The goal here is to add a delete button beneath every post, and once it is clicked, the corresponding row will be deleted from the table in the database.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import CreatePostForm
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import CreatePost

def create_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreatePostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit = False)
            post.save()
            messages.success(request, f'The post has been created.')
            return redirect('home_page')
    else:
        form = CreatePostForm()
    return render(request, 'post/create_post.html', {'form': form})

def view_post(request):
    context = CreatePost.objects.order_by('-dateCreated')
    return render(request, 'post/view_post.html', {'context': context})
```

So far, there is one page, `create_post.html`, that allows users to create a post.  There is a second page, `view_post.html`, that allows users to see all posts with the most recently added first.  I want to put a delete button beneath every post in `view_post.html`.

**view_post.html**

```
{% extends "home_page/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Volunteer Opportunities</h1>

    {% for x in context %}
    <h4>
        {{ x.task }}
        <small class="text-muted">Date Required: {{ x.dateRequired }}</small>
    </h4>
    <blockquote>
        <p>{{ x.description }}</p>
        <p>Date Posted: {{ x.dateCreated }}</p>
    </blockquote>
    <hr>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

I'm not sure if this is necessary, but below are `models.py` and the project `urls.py` file.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class CreatePost(models.Model):
    dateCreated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    task =  models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
    description = models.TextField()
    dateRequired = models.DateField(null = True)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from home_page.views import home
from post.views import create_post, view_post

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home, name = 'home_page'),
    path('create_post/', create_post, name = "create_post"),
    path('view_post/', view_post, name = "view_post"),
]
```

Comment: You need to add JS and Ajax code to handle data hide or refresh after button is clicked. If you can reload entire page then button with Ajax will by enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

In your url

```
path('delete/<int:id>', view_post.destroy),
```

In Your html inside for

```
<a href="/delete/{{ x.id }}">Delete</a>
```

views.py

```
def destroy(request, id):  
    post = CreatePost.objects.get(id=id)  
    post.delete()  
    return redirect("/yourhtml")
```

Comment: for deleting objects you should use POST request

Comment: It worked perfectly thank you very much for your help.  The only thing, I just did "path('delete/<int:id>', destroy)" rather than "view_post.destroy".  Again, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: To help other people https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.